# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED getting this error in peerjs involved website

Tags: heroku, deployment, webrtc, peerjs

I want to deploy my peerjs server. [Deploy PeerJS server on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084622/deploy-peerjs-server-on-heroku)
.I tried this. I deployed it on Heroku

```
myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
        host: 'https://host-name-here.com/',
        secure : true,
        port: 443
    })
```

I used this in client files

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I am getting this error on deployed site. On the local Site, it's working fine so there is some deployment problem involved.

Comment: Does ```host-name-here.com``` exist?  Does it resolve to that particular instance?

Comment: Yes. I created a peerjs server on Heroku. With different name obviously